# Setting initial 'default' opacity of points on a d3 map

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, leaflet

I have a d3.js map that will update the opacity of points based on a time range-slider.  The issue is that if I set the initial opacity of the points to a certain value, then this becomes global and the update function which updates the opacity won't work.  Code below:

```
 //Build time-slider in HTML

 <input id="timeslide" type="range" class="slider" min="0" max="25" value="0" step="1"   /><br>

 //Set values for time range slider
var inputValue = null;
var years = ["1993","1994","1995","1996","1997","1998","1999","2000","2001","2002","2003","2004","2005","2006","2007","2008","2009", "2010","2011","2012","2013","2014","2015","2016","2017","2018","2019"];

//load in the points and style
var feature = mapG.selectAll("circle")
        .data(SFData)
        .enter().append("circle")   
        .style("opacity", initialDateMatch) //How should I write this function?

    // when time slider input, call 'update' function
    d3.select("#timeslide-leaflet").on("input", function() {        
        update(+this.value, currentValue);   
    });

 //'update' function to update points' opacity
function update(value, currentValue) {

        //do some things to check current value of time slider to determine opacity
        document.getElementById("range-leaflet").innerHTML=years[value]
        inputValue = years[value];
        d3.selectAll(".features")
            .attr("opacity", dateMatch)

}

// 'Function to match time slider value to data properties value, to determine opacity
function dateMatch(data, value) {
    var date = (data.properties.Sign_Date);
    var year = date.substring(0, 4);
    var inputValueInt = parseInt(inputValue, 10);
    var yearInt = parseInt(year, 10);

    if (yearInt <= inputValueInt) {
        //console.log('match!'+ year)

     return ".7";
    } else {
        return "0";
    };
}
```

I would like all points that show up on the map to have a 'default' opacity of '.7'  Instead, as it is now, since I have no opacity set initially, they are all at 100% opaque.  Everything else works perfectly, how would I go about just getting all the points to be styled before the slider input is instantiated and the update function is called?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not possible to tell if the condition in the `if()` statement is satisfied or not at any point. Can you post what the value of `date` variable looks like? Also, `inputValue` is not defined in the `dateMatch()` function. Is it a global variable that is not included in your question? If it is undefined, then `parseInt(undefined, 10)` will always return `NaN`.

Comment: Terry - thanks for your response,  please see my edits above.  The opacity update function works perfectly - it's matching the 'date' of the object's properties to the date of the range slider.  The issue is setting an initial opacity.  Re: inputValue - this is defined globally as 'null' and then updated when time slider is instantiated.  I tried to set the initial opacity as .7 if inputValue == null, but this did not work - it set the opacity to ALWAYS be .7

Comment: you mix `style`-opacity and `attr`-opacity. `style`-opacity takes precedence

Comment: You are a lifesaver. That's all that was needed.  Thank you!